# BlackBerry Facebook auth without browser

Tags: blackberry, facebook

I want to implement Facebook authentication without using the browser. Instead, I will collect the user's id and password and use that to authenticate with Facebook.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [BlackBerry Facebook API](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/started/facebook.jsp).